# How to find total equity from balance sheet of a company?

Tags: india, equity, assets, balance-sheet, liabilities

I was looking for balance sheet of a company to know about it's total assets, liabilities and equity price. I tried apply basic formula to get equity, which is 'Assets = Liabilities + Equity'.

But, I found equity to be zero as both assets and liabilities were same. But in actually equity is not zero.

Link for balance sheet is :- https://www.moneycontrol.com/financials/infosys/balance-sheet/IT#IT
Assets = Liabilities ≈ 830.57 $ as per (March 2019)

And link for actual equity price is :-
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infosys
Which is approx 9.4 billion $ as per (2019)

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a bad job of normalizing data by MoneyControl. If you look at the [actual balance sheet](https://www.infosys.com/investors/reports-filings/quarterly-results/2019-2020/q4/documents/ifrs-usd-earnings-release.pdf) and [Yahoo Finance](https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/INFY/balance-sheet?p=INFY) you see a value for total shareholder's equity that more closely matches what's shown in their Wikipedia page.

To elaborate more, companies have a lot of freedom to report their finances in whatever categories they see fit (within very broad best-practices like US GAAP or IFRS). Aggregation sites have to take the wide variey of formats and "normalize" them in order to make them comparable across companies. Sometimes they do a bad job putting things in the right categories.

Also, since MoneyControl seems to be an India-based site, it's also possible that equity is treated more like an "liability" in their financial market, but that's beyond of my realm of knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the [Result in New Format](https://www.moneycontrol.com/financials/infosys/balance-sheetVI/IT#IT) function of that website, you will see that Share Capital is no longer part of Liabilities.

Comment: Could u plz elaborate more? What I'm understanding now is, share capital is equity? Basically, I'm looking in the terms of mathematics.

Comment: And further adding, what are the intentions behind two different form of balance sheet?